# ¿Qué significa "de estos pagos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

En el libro *Sapiens* de Yuval Harari leo lo siguiente:

> Estamos acostumbrados a pensar en nosotros como la única especie humana que hay, porque durante los últimos 10.000 años nuestra especie ha sido, efectivamente, la única especie humana **de estos pagos**.

¿Qué quiere decir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra *pago* tiene distintos significados, pero este en concreto se refiere a:

> [**pago<sup>2</sup>**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RSFJVnK)
>   Del lat. pagus.
>
> 1. m. Distrito determinado de tierras o heredades, especialmente de viñas u olivares.
> 2. m. Pueblo pequeño o aldea.
> 3. m. Lugar o región. U. m. en pl.
> 4. m. Arg., Bol. y Ur. Lugar en el que ha nacido o está arraigada una persona. U. m. en pl.

Como ves, la tercera acepción indica *usado más en plural* y es exactamente el uso que se hace en el fragmento que citas: el uso de *en estos pagos* es equivalente a decir *en estos lugares*.

Por tanto, cuando el autor indica:

> (...) nuestra especie ha sido, efectivamente, la única especie humana de estos pagos.

Sería equivalente a que dijera:

> (...) nuestra especie ha sido, efectivamente, la única especie humana en este rincón del universo.

Viniendo a decir que la especie humana ha sido la única presente en las galaxias más cercanas.

---

Huelga decir que esta palabra es conocida, pero en el habla coloquial seguramente no la oirías: tiene un tono algo formal (para mí al menos).

Comment: suena a que es común en argentina, bolivia y uruguay

Comment: En efecto, en Argentina es común y coloquial, aunque está algo pasada de moda. Me resulta raro verla en una traducción. La región donde vivo se llamaba antiguamente «Pago de los Arroyos».

Answer (score 1):

Como dice fedorqui, yo he visto que usan esa palabra algunos argentinos. La wikipedia la describe muy bien. Y resume:
La palabra castellana pago usada para designar a un territorio coincide con una acepción muy usada de la francesa pays y suele también coincidir con la más difundida en España de comarca.